# compare values from column field with values from column rows and print as checked and unchecked checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, compare

I have a simple db with 2 tables:

```
1. active_services            2. devices
------------------           ------------------------------
id   |  service                id | active_services_value
------------------           ------------------------------
1    | AD                      1  |  AD,DNS,DHCP
2    | FTP                     2  |  FTP,SMB
3    | DNS                     3  |  FTP
4    | DHCP                    4  |
5    | SMB                     5  |  AD Backup
6    | AD Backup
```

I use the values of service column in active_services as checkboxes for a form that will post the checked values to the table device, column active_service_values. My code looks like:

```
<?php

if($active_services_value != ""){   

// Need to generate a list of checkboxes from active_services but
// for each value in the active_services_field coresponding
// to the searched id (e.g for id 1, value1 = AD, value2 = DNS, 
// value3 = DHCP ) set the checkboxes as checked            


} else {  
// display the service in active_services as checkboxes

$q = "SELECT * from active_services";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);            
    while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){

    ?>              

<div class="col-xs-4"><input  type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]" value="<?php echo $list['service']; ?>"><?php echo $list['service'];?>
</div>
<?php   }   } ?> 
</div>

?>
```

My question is:

How do I display the "checked" checkboxes, giving the users the possibility to uncheck some of the checkboxes, while displaying also the remaining ones, unchecked, again, giving the users the possibility to check new options?

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Comment: Simple. See normalization.

Comment: As @Strawberry mentioned, you should normalize your tables (especially devices) to : 1 - ease data manipulation and 2 - increase performances. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: If the list of services is small and fixed (as in the example), then you can store a bit value instead.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you, you are right about normalizing the tables. This is something I'll do in the future for all my projects. However, for the current one, since it is already a "production environment"  I can't do much. Currently I just add some new options in the DB and some of the scripts, but that's all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark a checkbox "checked" by adding the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-checked) attribute to the input field. So if you retrieve the list of selected items from the database you can use those to determine if you should add the checked attribute to the input field.

It would become something like this:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT active_services_value FROM devices WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($serviceList);
$stmt->fetch();

//transform the list of services into an array
$services = explode($serviceList, ",");

$q = "SELECT * from active_services";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);            
while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){

?>              

<div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]"
           value="<?php echo $list['service'];?>"
           <?php if (in_array($list['service'], $services) { echo "checked"; } ?>>
    <?php echo $list['service'];?>
</div>
<?php   }   } ?> 
</div>
```

I also have a few additional points for improvement for you that are somewhat related to your question:

- As others have mentioned in the comments already you should normalize your tables (i.e. not putting all active services in one column, instead use a separate table for it containing `device,service` pairs)
- Instead of using the names of the services in the devices table you can better reference to the id of the services in the `active_services` table and set it up as a foreign key. That will improve performance and will guarantee consistency in your table (i.e. if set up correctly it will be impossible to use a non-existing service in your devices table).

Comment: Thank you for the code, with a few changes to match my scripts it works perfectly. I'll keep in mind your advices also for future projects. Thank you again.

Comment: The point about performance is a bit of a misconception, but the point about data integrity is spot on.